# Estimation of a defined integral

Tags: definite-integrals, estimation

I need to show that $$\left|\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{(2t-1)^3}{(\sqrt{1+t})^7}dt\right|<\frac{16}{125}$$

Evaluating it would be my last hope, but it wouldn't be easy wither. Is there a trick for that kind of problems?

Comment: The integrand is negative on the interval, so...

Comment: I forgot to add the absolute value

Comment: In that case, perhaps you can show what you've attempted so far?

Comment: This would make more sense if it was $(1-2t)^3$. Then you could argue that the integrand was smaller than $(1-2t)^3$. Integrating that would give you a value of $\frac{1}{8}=\frac{16}{128}<\frac{16}{125}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator is greater than 1. So the value is less than $\int_0^{0.5}(1-2t)^3dt=\frac{1}{8}=\frac{16}{128}<\frac{16}{125}$.

Comment: I had to think about it a bit. How can I still say that that what I have is positive, bcs I still need the absolute value of it and it gets lost in that way.

Comment: For all $t$ in the range 0 to 0.5 you have $2t-1\le 0$

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

Since your last hope is to evaluate the integral, you will be more than happy (I am sure !) to hear that $$8\left|\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{(2t-1)^3}{(\sqrt{1+t^7}}dt\right|=4 \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{7},\frac{1}{2};\frac{8}{7};-\frac{1}{128}\right)-6 \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{2}{7},\frac{1}{2};\frac{9}{7};-\frac{1}{128}\right)+$$ $$4 \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{7},\frac{1}{2};\frac{10}{7};-\frac{1}{128}\right)-\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{4}{7};\frac{11}{7};-\frac{1}{128}\right)$$ where appear  a bunch of Gaussian hypergeometric functions (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)).

The value of the rhs is $\approx 0.9999881703$